# Check whether file is open or not-Excel VBA

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I need to know that whether particular file is opened or not using VBA or VB.net.
If it is opened, execute required actions. If file is not opened need to open the file and execute actions.
EX.

```
If file is open then
     Do required things
else 
     **Open the file**
     Do required things
end if.
```

Found a by surfing INTERNET. But no answer.

Chandana

**strong text** *emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean opened by a particular instance of Excel.  You will generally have a reference to an `Excel.Application` object, either implicitly (e.g. if your app is Excel VBA or VSTO VB.NET) or because you have explicitly created an instance.

You can then iterate through the `Application.Workbooks` collection, looking for an instance that matches the file you're interested in, for example, by comparing the `Workbook.Path` property.

Note that in Excel, you can't open two workbooks with the same filename (but different directories) simultaneously.  So if you find a workbook with the same name as your file, but a different directory, you'll have to close it before opening your workbook.

Comment: Thanks Joe, My macro is given to another user to use. In the macro I need to open an another data base file(not the macro include excel file) separately and edit it. If user already opened the data base file programm opens a read only copy. My workings are not saved and give error msg. I need to prevet this. Thanks